# RESTLET 2.1RC1 : ChallengeResponse send from GWT client to server always NULL

Tags: gwt, authentication, restlet

I have :

- RESTLET GWT 2.1RC1 on the client
- RESTLET J2EE 2.1RC1 on the server

I have been banging my head over this but no matter what I try :

```
    ClientResource r = new ClientResource("/service" + UsersServiceProxy.URL);
    r.setChallengeRespon​se(ChallengeScheme.H​TTP_BASIC, "user1", "secret");
    r.setOnResponse(new Uniform() {
        public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
           .....
        }
    });
    r.get();
```

Or this code :

```
    UserServiceProxy userService = GWT.create(UserServiceProxy.class);
    userService.getClientResource().setReference(url);
    userService.getClientResource().setChallengeResponse(new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "user1", "secret"));
    userService.getUser(username + ":" + password, new Result<User>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                ......
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(User user) {
            .....
        }
    });
```

Problem :

On the server side no ChallengeResponse (==NULL) is received. Debugging with wireshark shows that no "Authorization:" is sent over the wire.

Using Chrome development tools I can however see that the XHR request is sent to : [http://user1:secret@​127.0.1.1:8888/servi​ce/user](http://user1%3asecret@%E2%80%8B127.0.1.1:8888/servi%E2%80%8Bce/user)

so here, username/password are passed to the server but not as authentication header ?
How can I get access to these server side ?

Is my setup incorrect?
Is this a regression of [this bug](http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1060)?

Comment: Using CURL or @REST console for Chrome, I can perfectly receive the Basic AUTH, which IMO rules out that this might be a server side issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No authorization header sent in Restlet GWT Edition 2.1RC1, I submitted a patch that fixes at least BASIC auth so I can move on.

see http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1060

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed. See next 2.1 RC2 and 2.0.11 versions.

See this issue for update on the fix:
http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1060

Comment: I am seeing the same problem, with the same code now. GWT2.2.0 and Restlet 2.1.2 ...

Comment: I should probably add that I see OPTIONS request on the server side, even though a GET is performed. Could it be related to something is doing an OPTIONS first and restlet doesn't expect a 401 for that?

Comment: Update: Actually, it is something wrong with the/my Restlet/GWT setup. Even 

`Representation representation = new ClientResource( "http://localhost:2882/programs/" ).get();` 

(without authentication on server) returns 'null'. But restlet.jse works with that code. Perhaps I need to downgrade...